# Api Resource Querying/collection methods

Tags: laravel

This is the code from my UserResource.

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $gender = Crypt::decryptString($this->gender);
    
    return ['gender' => $gender,'id' => 1];
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

I cannot query or use collection models on my API resource collection.

```
{"data":[{"gender":"m","id":1},{"gender":"m","id":1}]}
```

This is the data returned. I want to only get the ones with gender 'm'. This is just a test, I want to make the data returned much bigger, but first this simple example needs to work.

```
    Route::get('/test', function() {
        $probant = Probant::all();
        $a = UserResource::collection($probant);
        
        return $a;
});
```

`$a->where('gender','m')->get()` doesn't work.

```
$filtered = $a->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->gender == 'm';
});

$filtered->all();
```

This also doesn't work. I cannot filtered the data I receive from my API resource. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With `$a->where('gender','m')->get()` you are trying to query the collection returned by the resource, not your eloquent model.

Change to the following:

```php
$probant = Probant::where('gender','m')->get();

return UserResource::collection($probant);
```